# Plotting bar graph with the range in the x- axis -Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Suppose I have a data such as the following, I want to plot a bar graph which would show each value of range as separate bar in the x-axis and the count in the yaxis.

```
                 range  count
0                  0-2  172
1                02-05   82
2                05-10  117
3                10-15  164
4                15-20  141
5         20 and above  380
```

I tried the following,

```
plt.bar(a['range'], a['count'], color='blue')
```

But i am getting the following error,

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0-2
```

I tried converting it to string. Still the result is same. Can anybody help me in plotting this here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `plt.bar`, you need to specify as the first argument the left edges of the bars you want, not the labels. And to specify the xtick labels, you need to use the `plt.xticks` function. Something like this:

```
plt.bar(range(len(a['count'])), a['count'], color='blue')
plt.xticks(range(len(a['count'])), a['range'])
```